# C# Problema al actualizar registro con mysql "Windows Form"

Tags: c#, mysql

Bueno me manda este mensaje de error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'id_raza =8' at line 1"

Este es mi método para actualizar

```
public bool Actualizar(string consulta)
        {
            bool actualizado = false;
            int rows = 0;
            conexion.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, conexion);

            rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                actualizado = true;
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return actualizado;

        }
    }

}
```

ahora lo que hago cuando doy en el botón de actualizar

```
private void txbActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string actualizar = "UPDATE raza SET raza =" + txtRaza.Text + "WHERE id_raza =" + txtIdraza.Text;
            if (fn.Actualizar(actualizar))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Actualizado");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al actualizar");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bueno `txtRaza`= al valor que pongo por texbox txtIdraza=al valor que pongo por texbox

mi tabla en la BD de MySQL tiene los siguientes campos

```
id_raza= int,llave primaria,autoincrementable  
raza=varchar
```

cuando pongo en el id el valor 8 otro que tenga ya guardado en la bd y cualquier nombre para raza se genere el error, no sé donde este el error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es que `MySQL` espera como dato para la columna raza, una cadena pero no envía eso, además la palabra reservada `where`, siempre quedará pegada o concatenada con el valor que desee asignar para la columna `raza`.

Para solucionar esto, debería añadir las comillas al valor del `Textbox` , y dar un espacio al `where`

```
string actualizar = "UPDATE raza SET " +
                 " raza ='" + txtRaza.Text + "' WHERE id_raza =" + txtIdraza.Text;
```

Claro que esto es un error de seguridad, concatenar valores directamente . debería utilizar sentencias preparadas, para la cuál recomendaría [revisar la siguiente documentación.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Prepare)

Comment: Gracias amigo funciona perfecto